# Delete a child object in Django database

Tags: python, django, django-models

Costumer and Worker models. Costumer inherited from User, and Worker inherited from Costumer, when I do

```
 worker.delete(),
```

it will delete all the related object in all three tables, how can I do, it will only delete the data in Worker table, and data in rest of tables remain(assume, one costumer doesnt want be a worker longer, but he still want to be a costumer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to 'demote' a model to a superclass, nor to 'promote' a model to a subclass.

If you need to modify the original records, rather than creating a new set, you'll probably have to use a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) like...

```
DELETE FROM <the_worker_table_name> WHERE id=<the_worker_object_id>
```

...then re-select the object as type `Costumer` for any further processing.