# Raw SQL query in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

Is there any nothing wrong with this raw query?

```
Worker.objects.raw('Delete from customer_worker Where customer_ptr_id= %s', [customer.id])
```

Customer id returns a string, but it seems like nothing happen, the object is still there after the execution.

The object Worker is a child object from `Customer`, I want to remain the customer, but delete the `Worker` object.

Here are the `Customer` and `Worker` models:

```
class Customer(User):                                                    
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description=models.TextField(null=True)
    phone=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    isWorker=models.BooleanField()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):                                        
        self.slug=slugify(self.username)                                          
        super(Customer,self).save(*args, **kwargs)                             

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username


class Worker(Customer):
    comment=models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=True)
    keyword=models.ManyToManyField('job.JobGenre', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the django ORM for this? It should be as simple as `Worker.objects.filter(ptr=costumer).delete()`.

Comment: how can i do it? the object Worker is a child object from costumer, I want to remain the costumer, but delete the worker object

Comment: Update the question with your models.

Comment: btw [No checking is done on the SQL statement that is passed in to .raw(). Django expects that the statement will return a set of rows from the database, but does nothing to enforce that. If the query does not return rows, a (possibly cryptic) error will result.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: FWIW, it's related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164591/delete-a-child-object-in-django-database).

Answer (score 6):

You can delete your record(s) directly via `connection.cursor()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)):

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM costumer_worker WHERE costumer_ptr_id = %s', [costumer.id])
connection.commit()
```

But, the thing you're trying to do looks too simple to write SQL directly, use django ORM instead.

Comment: when i use worker.delete() , it will delete all object from the parent model and child model

Comment: delete() in django is super slow since it needs to figure out foreign keys relations etc. in case of millions of records the above solution is better

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing comitting the transcation. Based on your settings, you may need to add :
`transaction.commit_unless_managed()` in django 1.4   ( not needed in django 1.5, since default settings are different)

Comment: i put transaction.commit_unless_managed() after it , but still nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

use this line:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
with transaction.commit_on_success():
   cursor.execute('DELETE FROM costumer_worker WHERE costumer_ptr_id = %s', [costumer.id])
   connection.commit()
```